# What is the best place to ask about buggy behavior?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure whether I should be using civicrm.stackexchange.com, or the Forum, for this sort of situation.  In this case, we're trying to get the new A/B emailing functionality to work, and it's proving incredibly erratic on our site.  I can't create a formal bug report because I need some community input to see if others are getting the same kind of behavior.

This seems like a Forum thing, but I'm not sure - hence, I'm posting in Meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SE site is a good place for this. To maintain the Q&A style that allows the community to help you solve the problem, please avoid posing the question like "Is xyz happening to anyone else?" or "Problems with CiviMail". Just lay out the problem as specifically as you can, share any relevant facts you've learned, and let us know what things you've tried to resolve it. It could be that the answer is "Yes, I can confirm this is a bug. Please file a bug report".

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Hopefully others will see this in Meta when wondering from the same kind of situation.